# Calling object literal function with this returning TypeError

Tags: javascript, this, javascript-objects

I am having a scoping issue. I have a simply object literal function, with a number of methods. I am trying to call method4(), from method1()

```
var myObjectFunc = function() {

return {
    method1: function() {
        // call method4 here and pass value
    },
    method2: function() {

    },
    method3: function() {

    },
    method4: function() {

    }
}
}
```

I have tried numerous ways with 'this':

Attempt one:

```
var myObjectFunc = function() {

var that = this;

return {
    method1: function() {
        // call method4 here and pass value
        var myName = 'Peter';
        that.method4(myName);
    },
    method2: function() {

    },
    method3: function() {

    },
    method4: function(val) {
        console.log(val);
    }
}
}
```

Attempt two:

```
var myObjectFunc = function() {

return {
    method1: function() {
        // call method4 here and pass value
        var myName = 'Peter';
        this.method4(myName);
    },
    method2: function() {

    },
    method3: function() {

    },
    method4: function(val) {
        console.log(val);
    }
}
}
```

Both of which return the error:

```
TypeError: that.method4 is not a function
```

Comment: Your second attempt seems to be working. `myObjectFunc().method1()` gives `'Peter'`.

Comment: how did you invoke `method1()`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var myObjectFunc = function() {

  var ret = {
      method1: function() {
          // call method4 here and pass value
          var myName = 'Peter';
          ret.method4(myName);
      },
      method2: function() {

      },
      method3: function() {

      },
      method4: function(val) {
          console.log(val);
      }
  }

  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Although is it the correct way to write literal like this? I'm trying to learn best practices

Comment: If you want the object to be able to access itself, this is - afaik - the way to do it. The `this` operator is only available in functions, not objects.

Comment: @ThorJacobsen That's not true. For example: `({a:function() {console.log(this)}}).a()` returns the object.

Comment: @ThorJacobsen, if you need these methods to always reference this `ref`, and you know that you'll assign them to a different object, or pass them as a callback-function. Then, is this the way to go. *(methods are kind of bound to ref)* In every other case, you have options, with particular pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const myObjectFunc = () => ({
  method1() {
    // call method4 here and pass value
    const myName = 'Peter'
    this.method4(myName)
  },
  method2() {

  },
  method3() {

  },
  method4(val) {
    console.log(val)
  }
})
```

Then:

```
myObjectFunc().method1()
```

logs `'Peter'`.